# ArgumentException in asynchronous webservice calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, exception, iis

I'm running into a problem, I haven't experienced before. I'm calling a method asynchronously, via the BeginXXX/EndXX pattern, with an extra wrapper for some timing functionality, like so:

```
BeginGetStuffTimed(arguments)
{
    var timingstuff = TimingStuff;
    var callback = new AsyncResult(CallbackMethod);
    service.BeginGetStuff(CallbackMethod, timingstuff);
}

CallbackMethodTimed(IAsyncResult result)
{
     SaveTiming(result.AsyncState...);
     service.EndGetStuff;
}
```

Now every once in a while, an exception gets thrown:

> Async End called on wrong channel.
>   Parameter name: result

Since it doesn't occur always this kind of puzzles me. I was thinking IIS couldn't keep up with requests and goes fubar, so I added a pause in my calling code and this does seem to work. The longer the pause, the less frequent the exception.

Of course this is no real solution, so I'm looking for some insights into this matter.

Edit: upon further inspection this seems to be unrelated to IIS, IIS can process up to 5000 (per CPU) simultaneous threads. I'm pushing nowhere near this limit.

Comment: could it be that you are recreating the service instance somewhere in the code after some time or maybe after a failure? The EndGet call has to be made from the same instance the BeginGet call was issued to, so if you recreate the service instance, you would get that error message.

Comment: I've been looking into this, but this doesn't seem to be the case. For every instance of my Screen construct a new wrapper gets instantiated and a call is made.